# CSS Text align override x y

Tags: css, text, alignment

i do have problems in align texts which are in a rec tag. 
followed the code and two pictures which are descripe the case.

HTML:

```html
<g class="v-label v-morphable-label viz-axis-label v-axis-item index_0" fill="#333333" font-size="10px" font-weight="normal" font-family="'72-Web',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-style="normal" categorylabel-id="0" transform="translate(0,0)">
<rect class="viz-axis-label-rect" fill="transparent" x="1" y="1" width="161.85644531" height="12.475">
</rect>
<g class="v-axis-label-wrapper">
<g>
<text x="129.52148437" y="11.2375">DACH</text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
```

i do want to align the text to left to the begin of the rect-tag. 
attached are to pictures from the debugging mode to see which element is how long and how they fit in each other. i tried it with transform:translate(-5%, -0%). 
which works but it will not align the texts they are still center but i could read it at least. much better would be the texts will be aligned left, too. 
i would appreciate any hints. 
[text tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pr99.png)
[rect tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDtv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for.

Do you want the text to be *inside* of the rect tags and aligned to the left? Like this?

```css
.viz-axis-label-rect {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

g text {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<g class="v-label v-morphable-label viz-axis-label v-axis-item index_0" fill="#333333" font-size="10px" font-weight="normal" font-family="'72-Web',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-style="normal" categorylabel-id="0" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <rect class="viz-axis-label-rect" fill="transparent" x="1" y="1" width="161.85644531" height="12.475" style=" width: 100%; display: block;">
    <g class="v-axis-label-wrapper">
      <g>
        <text x="129.52148437" y="11.2375">DACH</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </rect>
</g>
```